# can i add where statement to hasMany or belongsTo in laravel 5.1?

Tags: laravel-5.1

i'm trying to implement relations in my laravel 5.1 app the flow is - after user register he needs to register it's client as well, before he does it the `client_id` field in the `users` table is 0 so i get an error for it...is it possible to do something like

```
 public function users(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\User')->where('client_id', '>' , 0);
}
```

the returned error is:

```
ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 129: 
No query results for model [App\Models\Client].
```

i saw some examples like that in older versions of laravel but it's not working for me...

thanks for the help :)

Comment: Would be very helpful to know what error you get.

Comment: sure man, sorry, that's the error returns: `ModelNotFoundException in Builder.php line 129:
No query results for model [App\Models\Client].`

Comment: Some thought: are Client and User define both in App\Models\? Have you imported User in the Client  with the keyword "use"?

Comment: If you remove the where clause does it work?

Comment: the where it's just an example mate, i'm not using it... i asked if there's a way to perform something like that to avoid the error that i'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

yes.. you can use where statement inside belongsto or hasMany.. Im using it too..like

```
public function data()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Data')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('functional', '1');
}
```

ModelnotFound Exception..

You need to import the Model to Controller to display data..

on top of controller.. add

```
<?php

namespace Buzzeee\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\User;
```

It should be working by then..